# If I am dealt Q♢ K♢ 7♠ 3♢ 5♠ and hold the Q♢ and K♢, how do I calculate the number of possible hands that yield 1 pair of Jacks or Better?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations, poker

For example,

If I am dealt Q$\diamondsuit$ K$\diamondsuit$ 7$\spadesuit$ 3$\diamondsuit$ 5$\spadesuit$ and hold the Q$\diamondsuit$ and K$\diamondsuit$, how do I calculate the number of possible hands that yield 1 pair of Jacks or Better?

So far, I have:

$\frac{2{3\choose 1}{41\choose 2} +2{4\choose 2}{37\choose 1}}{47\choose 3}$ = $\frac{5364}{16215}$ = .33

This is off roughly 2% according to this [poker calculator](http://www.beatingbonuses.com/vp.php). Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Just to clarify: you will have $\diamondsuit Q$ and $\diamondsuit K$ and three more cards, not including $\spadesuit 7$ or $\diamondsuit 3$ or $\spadesuit 5$, and you want to know the probability of two jacks or better?  Right?

Comment: Sorry, I am new to asking questions. The numerator represents the number of ways to draw a single instance of the held cards and then 2 other cards (that don’t improve the hand) plus the number of ways to draw a pair of aces or jacks and then any other card (that doesn’t improve the hand)

Answer (score 3):

Since you have not explained your working I'm guessing a bit, but it looks like you have calculated the probability of two kinds of hand.  However there are many possibilities for getting two jacks or better from your hand:

- two jacks, or two queens, or two kings or two aces;
- three twos or threes or...  or queens or kings or aces;
- flush;
- full house (in two ways);
- etc etc etc.

Comment: Straight, three deuces, etc.

Comment: When I said one pair of jacks or better, I am referring to the value of the pair, not other hands that could be made. I will try to clarify my question. Thanks David